# Calculate sales tax according to the price

Tags: java

I am trying to do on the java assignment and the scenario is as follows:

A sales tax of 7% is levied on all goods and services consumed. It is also mandatory that all the price tags should include the sales tax. For example, if an item has a price tag of $107, the actual price is $100 and $7 goes to the sales tax.

Write a program using a loop to continuously input the tax-inclusive price (as "double"); compute the actual price and the sales tax (in "double"); and print the results rounded to 2 decimal places. The program shall terminate in response to input of -1; and print the total price, total actual price, and total sales tax.

However, when I try to compute the sales tax, instead of showing this:

Enter·the·tax-inclusive·price·in·dollars·(or·-1·to·end): 107

Actual·Price·is: $100.00

Sales·Tax·is: $7.00

My calculation shows this:

Enter the tax-inclusive price in dollars (or -1 to end): 107

Actual price is $99.51

Sales Tax is: $7.49

I am not sure what's wrong with my coding.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SalesTax{

  public static void main(String[] args) {



// Declare constants
      final double SALES_TAX_RATE = 0.07;
  final int SENTINEL = -1;        // Terminating value for input

  // Declare variables
  double price, actualPrice, salesTax;  // inputs and results
  double totalPrice = 0.0, totalActualPrice = 0.0, totalSalesTax = 0.0;  // to accumulate


  // Read the first input to "seed" the while loop
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the tax-inclusive price in dollars (or -1 to end): ");
  price =  in.nextDouble();

  while (price != SENTINEL) {
     // Compute the tax

     salesTax = SALES_TAX_RATE * price;
      actualPrice = price - salesTax;


     // Accumulate into the totals
     totalPrice = actualPrice + salesTax;
     totalActualPrice = actualPrice + actualPrice; 
     totalSalesTax = salesTax + salesTax;
     // Print results
     System.out.println("Actual price is $" + String.format("%.2f",actualPrice));
     System.out.println("Sales Tax is: $" + String.format("%.2f",salesTax));


     // Read the next input
     System.out.print("Enter the tax-inclusive price in dollars (or -1 to end): ");
     price =  in.nextDouble();
     // Repeat the loop body, only if the input is not the sentinel value.
     // Take note that you need to repeat these two statements inside/outside the loop!
  }
  // print totals
  System.out.println("Total price is: " + String.format("%.2f",totalPrice));
  System.out.println("Total Actual Price is: " + String.format("%.2f",totalActualPrice));
  System.out.println("Total sales tax is: " + String.format("%.2f",totalSalesTax));




  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong with these two lines:

```
salesTax = SALES_TAX_RATE * price;
actualPrice = price - salesTax;
```

You're calculating the sales on the already-saled price, try following me:

Your `price` is the composition of the `actualPrice` and the tax on `actualPrice`:

```
price = actualPrice + SALES_TAX_RATE * actualPrice
```

so you can mathematically do the following passages:

```
price = actualPrice * (1 + SALES_TAX_RATE)

actualPrice = price / (1 + SALES_TAX_RATE)
```

So, try changing the assigment of `actualPrice`, then calculate the tax on your `actualPrice`:

```
salesTax = SALES_TAX_RATE * actualPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate actual price first and with the help of that calculate sales tax rate
and instead of using this
`salesTax = SALES_TAX_RATE * price; actualPrice = price - salesTax;`

calculate using this:
`actual_price = price / 1.07; tax_price = price - actual_price;`

1.07 came from dividing tax % with 100 and adding 1 to it(you can do this to any amount of %)

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar and used this logic. You need to divide the sales tax by 100 like 7/100 with 7 being the percentage of your tax variable or you can multiply by .01 then take the result of that and add it to your variable's total value. 1% is .01 of 100%. So 7% would be .07 multiplied by your variable and added to the total you are trying to calculate. If you want precision and not rounded to the nearest integer then just set parameters on the Math.round function or don't even use it at all.

```java
public static void solve(double meal_cost, int tip_percent, int tax_percent) {
    double tip = Math.round((tip_percent * .01) * meal_cost);
    double tax = Math.round((tax_percent * .01) * meal_cost);
    int total_cost = (int)(meal_cost + tip + tax);
    System.out.println(total_cost);
}
```

Comment: re-read the question please. You are doing the exact same mistake OP did in their function. OP isn't asking how to add tax, but how to extract tax.

Answer (score 0):

here is the changes for correct calculation

```
while (price != SENTINEL) {
    // Compute the tax
    salesTax = SALES_TAX_RATE * price;
    actualPrice = price - salesTax;

    // Accumulate into the totals
    totalPrice += actualPrice + salesTax;
    totalActualPrice += actualPrice; 
    totalSalesTax += salesTax;

    // Print results
    System.out.println("Actual price is $" + String.format("%.2f", actualPrice));
    System.out.println("Sales Tax is: $" + String.format("%.2f", salesTax));

    // Read the next input
    System.out.print("Enter the tax-inclusive price in dollars (or -1 to end): ");
    price =  in.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your sales tax calculation, try:

```
final double SALES_TAX_RATE = 7;

salesTax = price / (100 + SALES_TAX_RATE) * SALES_TAX_RATE;
```

Comment: "107" is an example, you should explain how to solve his problem generally; however, in his example "price / 107" is equals to 1, and it works only beacuse we're in a particulare case: your answer is incorrect or incomplete

Comment: The price is 107% of the actual price. Dividing the price by 107 gives you the value of 1% of the price, multiplying it by 7 gives the 7% sales tax. Though I should have used variables for the tax percentage instead of limiting it to 7%.